# Adding Quick Tabs Programmatically to a node is not working

Tags: nodes, entities, blocks

I'm writing below code in my node--type.tpl.php, but only empty page is loading when i load the node page.Can you please help in knowing my mistake.
What i need to add to display quicktab and its corresponding viewmode content?
my code is:

```
<?php
 $nid=$node->nid;

$tabs['Home'] = array(
  'title' => t('Home'),
  'type' => 'node',
  'nid' => $nid,
  'viewmode_home' => TRUE,
  'hide_title' => FALSE,
);
$tabs['About'] = array(
  'title' => t('About'),
  'type' => 'node',
  'nid' => $nid,
  'viewmode_about' => TRUE,
  'hide_title' => FALSE,
);


$quicktabs['qtid'] = 111; //given a random number
$quicktabs['tabs'] = $tabs;
$quicktabs['style'] = 'Mac';
$quicktabs['ajax'] = FALSE;
print theme('quicktabs', $quicktabs);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using node--typename.tpl.php

```
$tabs = array(
      array(
        'title' => t('Overview'),
        'type' => 'view',
        'vid' => 'product_tabs',
        'display' => 'block_1',
        'args' => $node->nid,
        'weight' => 0,
      ),
      array(
        'title' => t('Dimensions & Weight'),
        'type' => 'view',
        'vid' => 'product_tabs',
        'display' => 'block_4',
        'args' => $node->nid,
        'weight' => 1,
      ),
      array(
        'title' => t('Shipping'),
        'type' => 'view',
        'vid' => 'ps3_games',
        'display' => 'default',
        'args' => $node->nid,
        'weight' => 2,
      ),
      array(
        'title' => t('Ratings & Reviews (' . $node->comment_count . ')' ),
        'type' => 'view',
        'vid' => 'product_tabs',
        'display' => 'block_3',
        'args' => $node->nid,
        'weight' => 3,
      ),
    );
    $qtoptions = array(
      'style' => 'Zen',
      'ajax' => FALSE,
    );
    $qtname = 'commerce_product23';
    $quicktabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs($qtname,$qtoptions,$tabs);
    print drupal_render($quicktabs['content']);
```

works with views, but if I try to use nodes it does not.

**You should try another method.**

**Create a Quicktab using the Quicktabs UI. Then create a custom module to override the settings/output of the quicktab using the machine name to target a specific quicktab**

For Example:

```
 function mymodule_quicktabs_alter($quicktabs) { 
    $nid = $node->nid
        if ($quicktabs->machine_name == 'quick_tab_front_page') { 
        $quicktabs->tabs = array(
          0 => array(
        'nid' => $nid,
        'view_mode' => 'full',
        'hide_title' => 1,
        'title' => 'Full',
        'weight' => '-99',
        'type' => 'node',
          ),
          1 => array(
        'nid' => $nid,
        'view_mode' => 'teaser',
        'hide_title' => 1,
        'title' => 'Teaser',
        'weight' => '-99',
        'type' => 'node',
          ),
        );
        $quicktabs->renderer = 'quicktabs';
        $quicktabs->style = 'Arrows';
        $quicktabs->options = array();
        }
        }
```

Comment: i tried this code in node--type.tpl.php file ,and adding only quicktabs of type node.                                                                                                 //Node
$custom_tabs[] = array(
  'nid' => 1,
  'view_mode' => 'full',
  'hide_title' => 1,
  'title' => 'Tab with a node'
  'weight' => -98,
  'type' => 'node',
);                         The problem is if i add 'nid' =>node_no of type corresponding node_type,then node page itself is not loading.

Comment: `'nid' =>node_no of type corresponding node_type` huh? what are you trying to do here? what do you want as nid?

Comment: i declared  $nid=$node->nid; in my node--type.tpl.php file and 'nid' =>$nid

Comment: i want quicktabs for a node with different view_modes

Comment: then use for example `'view_mode' => 'teaser',`

Comment: i used 'view_mode' => 'my_viewmode_name' , the code is working fine if i addit in block,by enabling php code, but in node--type.tpl.php file it is not working. I'm not understanding why? Do u have any clue?

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't have a clue why node--type.tpl.php won't let us use node quick tabs. I got it to work with views tho.

Comment: @rls looks like custom module is the only way to go.